# How to make selectable option in OPC-UA?

Tags: node.js, opc-ua, node-opcua

Assuming having a read/write variable called Fruit.
Selectable options are Apple, Pear, Strawberry & Pineapple.

Using [OptionSetType](https://reference.opcfoundation.org/v104/Core/docs/Part5/7.17/) seems to be the most suiteable way.
But I did not find any examples for [node-opcua](https://node-opcua.github.io/api_doc/2.0.0/classes/optionset.html)

Can somebody provide an example or is there another/better/smarter way?

Answer (score 0):

Enumeration become my best friend

```
  const fruitEnumType = ownNameSpace.addEnumerationType({
    browseName: "Fruits",
    enumeration: ["apple", "pear", "strawberry", "pineapple"],
  });

  let selected = "apple";

  ownNameSpace.addVariable({
    browseName: "Fruit",
    componentOf: folder,
    dataType: fruitEnumType,
    value: {
      get: () =>
        new Variant({
          dataType: DataType.String,
          value: selected,
        }),
      set: (value: Variant) => {
        selected = value.value;
        return StatusCodes.Good;
      },
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The UAVariable class in node-opcua comes with two helpers methods that make it easy to deal with enumeration.  `readEnumValue` and `writeEnumValue` .

You will find this form more practical:

```js
const fruit2 = ownNameSpace.addVariable({
    browseName: "Fruit2s",
    componentOf: myObject,
    dataType: fruitEnumType
});
fruit2.writeEnumValue("strawberry");

console.log("enum value       = ", fruit2.readEnumValue());
console.log("enum value name  = ", fruit2.readEnumValue().name);
console.log("enum value value = ", fruit2.readEnumValue().value);

console.log("dataValue is  ", fruit2.readValue().toString());
```

```
enum value       =  { value: 2, name: 'strawberry' }
enum value name  =  strawberry
enum value value =  2
dataValue is   { /* DataValue */
   value: Variant(Scalar<Int32>, value: 2)
   statusCode:      Good (0x00000)
   serverTimestamp: 2021-01-23T08:59:04.273Z $ 990.400.000
   sourceTimestamp: 2021-01-23T08:59:04.273Z $ 990.400.000
}
```

Note: that you don't need to use the get/set form as well as the value is already store inside the variable.